# Simulate mouse click at x,y using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to simulate a mouse click at x,y co-ordinates using javascript.
I am using the following functions which works fine for most of the html elements:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    event.initEvent("click", true, true);
    document.elementFromPoint(x, y).dispatchEvent(event);
}, 1000);
```

However,it is unable to select a text-box(input html control) when a co-ordinate contained within the text box is clicked.

Is there anyway i can simulate selecting an input html element?

Note:There is something on top of the webpage and i am kinda passing the click operation to the webpage below it using javascript.

Comment: You could also dispatch the focus event.

Comment: @crush i tired setting the focus to the element at x,y both before and after the click but it didn't work. If a text-box already has focus, it never loses focuses on simulating mouse click except when the simulated click clicks on a button or a link.

Comment: If it has focus, then why do you need to click on it?

Comment: coz there could be other textboxes that i might need to select

Comment: I don't follow why using `focus` would be a problem then. When you trigger the `focus` event, it will move `focus` to the input that you want to focus. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: i don't know what i am actually clicking(as far as the code goes). I load a webpage. i have something on top of this page and i want to pass on the click event to the webpage below it.

Comment: basically i am injecting JavaScript from the top layer to the webpage below it to simulate clicks..the top layer catches the clicks and passes it on to the webpage below it.

Comment: the top layer is not an html layer. if i load a page that has a text-box which is already focused than i can click and select any other text box using the `focus()` method. If there is no focused text-box than i a out of luck.

Comment: What do you mean it's not an HTML layer? Can you add an image or something to help illustrate what you mean?

Comment: @crush i am embedding a browser in my application

Answer (score 0):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49uMG/) demonstrates the problem you are likely facing. When you execute `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` it doesn't get beyond your overlay because your overlay is at the front of z-index of your document.

In order to get past this, you can bind a click handler to the overlay, quickly hide it, get the element underneath, then show the overlay again.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49uMG/2)

```
overlay.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var element = null;

    this.style.display = 'none'; //Hide it.
    element = document.elementFromPoint(e.x, e.y); //Get your element
    this.style.display = ''; //Unhide it.

    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    event.initEvent("click", true, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

This will click behind your overlay. However, [simply triggering the `click` event](http://jsfiddle.net/49uMG/3/) on a text input element won't give it focus.

I'm not sure what jQuery is doing in the source...I tried to track it down, but couldn't. However, using jQuery's `focus()` method [works here](http://jsfiddle.net/49uMG/4/).

```
overlay.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var element = null;

    this.style.display = 'none'; //Hide it.
    element = document.elementFromPoint(e.x, e.y);
    this.style.display = ''; //Unhide it.

    $(element).focus();
});
```